# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Debo realizar una consulta desde php a mysql y estoy obteniendo todo el rato error. No se que debo hacer con el fetch_assoc().
A un comprañero, con otra consulta si que le funciona y le devuelve resultado.
Agradecería mucho que alguien me explicase que debo hacer

````
$db = @new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$basedatos);
    if ($db->connect_errno) 
        die("<p class='MSGError'>Error al conectar a la Base de datos: (".$db->connect_errno.") ".utf8_encode($db->connect_error)."</p>"."$servidor,$usuario,$password,$basedatos");

    mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
    $query = "SELECT nombre FROM biblieuss.bibliotecario UNION SELECT nombre FROM biblieuss.lector";
    //die("..."."$query"."...");
    $result = $db->query($query);
?> 
<center>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>

    </tr>
<?php
    while ($fila=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo("\n <tr>   
                <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                </tr>");
    }
    $db->close();
?>
    </table>  
</center> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso te está pasando porque el query no te está devolviendo ningún registro. Lo resuelves colocando este `if` deltante del `while`:

```
if($result->num_rows)
```

Así, si no hay datos, no intenta hacer el `fetch_assoc()` que es el que te está dando el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final conseguir darme cuenta de lo pasaba. Se trataba de la forma de nombrar  “biblieuss.bibliotecario” en la consulta SQL, de esta manera no la reconocía, lo correcto era “bibliotecario”